# Sort nested properties on 3 Lists

Tags: c#

How would one sort nested lists in place:

List of JobCollection

List of Jobs (sort by string Sponsor)

List of Items (sort by int Order)

**Data model class structure:**

```
public class JobCollection
{
        public string Collection { get; set; }

        public virtual TrulyObservableCollection<Job> Jobs { get; private set; } = new TrulyObservableCollection<Job>();
}

public class Job
{
        public virtual JobCollection JobCollection { get; set; }

        public string JobGUID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        public string Sponsor { get; set; }

        public virtual TrulyObservableCollection<Item> Items { get; private set; } = new TrulyObservableCollection<Item>();

}
public class Item
{
        public virtual Job Job { get; set; }

        [Key]
        public string ItemGUID { get; set; } = Guid.NewGuid().ToString();

        public int Order { get; set; }
}
```

I've tried various ways but not getting anywhere with it such as:

```
EntireCollection.SelectMany(o => o.Jobs).ToList().ForEach(d => d.Sponsor = d.Items.OrderBy(e => e.Order).ToList());

elem => elem.Jobs.OrderBy(
job => job.Items.OrderBy(
    item => item.Order
)

Argh!
```

Comment: Do you want to sort them internally? Can't you sort on the get property?

Comment: is this code even compiling? How do you set `Sponsor`, a `string` property, with a `List<Item>`?

Comment: other point, `OrderBy` does not order collections in place, it will "create another collection" of type IEnumerable<T>, you should rethink your approach

Comment: JobCollection > string Collection is a dropdown selection. DataGrid displays Jobs. RowDetails displays Items inside another DataGrid.

Answer (score 0):

The easiest way to do it, but not suggested.

```
jobCollection.ForEach( (jobCol) => 
    { 
        jobCol.Jobs.ForEach( (job) => 
        {
            job.Items.OrderBy( item => item.Order );
        });
        jobCol.Jobs.OrderBy( (job) => job.Sponsor );
    });
```